# How to efficiently merge a list of deeply nested HashMaps?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, merge, hashmap

Suppose I have a list of hashmaps (`<String, Object>`). Values can be either scalar types or a nested HashMap with the same type.

I need to merge a list of this maps into a final HashMap, each map in the list has higher precedence than the one before. Also the merge has to be deep: i.e.:

```
map1   = {root: {a: a, b: {c: c, d: d}}}
map2   = {root: {a: a, b: {c: x}}
result = {root: {a: a, b: {c: x, d: d}}}
```

In the previous example, the sub tree `b` in `map2` does not override the whole subtree in `map1`. It just overrides the leaves that are duplicated.

The code I have right now looks like this and works ok:

```java
public static Map<String, Object> merge(List<Map<String, Object>> configs) {
    return configs.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .reduce(new LinkedHashMap<>(), ConfigMerger::mergeMaps);
}

public static Map<String, Object> mergeMaps(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> other) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(map.size() + other.size());
    result.putAll(map);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : other.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object val2 = entry.getValue();
        Object val1 = result.get(key);

        if (val1 instanceof Map && val2 instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, Object> nestedResult = mergeMaps((Map<String, Object>) val1, (Map<String, Object>) val2);
            result.put(key, nestedResult);
        } else {
            result.put(key, val2);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The only issue is that `result.putAll(map);` is a bit wasteful. I do that for every nested map in each one of the original maps.

I tried a slightly more complicated approach, which is around 20% faster, and yet the most expensive method is the `HashSet.addAll`:

```java
// (assumes the list in reversed order)
public static Map<String, Object> merge2(List<Map<String, Object>> configs) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> allKeys = new HashSet<>();
    for (Map<String, Object> config : configs) {
        allKeys.addAll(config.keySet());
    }
    for (String key : allKeys) {
        if (configs.get(0).get(key) instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> nestedConfigs = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map<String, Object> config : configs) {
                if (config.get(key) instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
                    nestedConfigs.add((Map<String, Object>) config.get(key));
                }
            }
            result.put(key, merge2(nestedConfigs));
        } else {
            for (Map<String, Object> config : configs) {
                if (config.containsKey(key)) {
                    result.put(key, config.get(key));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any other approach I could try that could help me squeeze a bit more of performance out of this?

For context, the maps are usually huge (hundreds of subtrees) and the nesting level up to fifty sometimes.

Comment: If your code is working, the question might be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: if：
`map1   = {root: {a: abc, b: {c: c, d: d}}}`,
`map2   = {root: {a: qwe, b: {c: x}}`. the result wille be what structure????

Comment: `{root: {a: qwe, b: {c: x, d: d}}`

Comment: This might not be the answer you want to hear, but this is the only one I will ever give to someone having this problem. HashMaps are tremendously inefficient, much more when talking about multidimensionality (lists, nested, etc.). Additionally, if their sizes are so big, it seems clear that you have modelled through code what you should have done via another resource like a DB. In any case, replacing almost any part with a more efficient option such as plain arrays (even 2D or 3D or various of them) would have a noticeable impact on performance and memory usage (out of space)...

Comment: ... (continuation from previous comment) I have done that myself many times. I do tend to rely on multidimensional HashMaps often because they are an easy way to create somehow complex data setups, although never up to the level which you seemed to have reached here. Afterwards, when trying to optimise the code, I gradually replace them with more efficient collections. In this case, I would start with the inner parts, the ones storing the final results. As said, you could replace one single HashMap with various arrays and it would still be very worthy.

Comment: On Code Review@SE: [Merge a list of deeply nested HashMaps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/285398/93149).

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing your own *map*.

It would require a re-factor of your code.

I presume there would be a subtle increase in performance—possibly negligible.

```java
abstract class Value {

}

class ScalarNumber extends Value {
    Number value;
}

class ScalarBoolean extends Value {
    boolean value;
}

class ScalarChar extends Value {
    char value;
}

class Values extends Value {
    List<Value> list;
}

class Entry extends Value {
    String key;
    Value value;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how that would help with the performance of the merging itself.

Comment: @Cristian, so, the object you'd be creating would be taking up less resources.

Comment: So here's the problem with a map built this way: how do you build a `get(key)` method? You would need to loop through the `list` and check for the existence of the key, which is O(n). Where as in a HashMap, a get operation is O(1).

Comment: @Cristian, I see what you mean.  That, I am unsure of.  I do know though, that decreasing the object's resources will typically increase performance.  The reduction from the loop may be negated by the increase of using a smaller object.  You would have to implement it and check, which may not be worth the effort.

Comment: @Cristian, as a note, typically, designs that follow this pattern will be implemented in a _node-structure_, as opposed to a nested map.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations that may or may not help as I'm not in position to test with your datasets.

`HashMap` might perform rehash of internal tables when number of entries exceeds the maps load factor as you add loop over `other`. You have mostly accounted for this with `Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(map.size() + other.size());`. In JDK19+ there is a slightly better call which scales up the size by the load factor so there shouldn't be a rehash event:

```
Map<String, Object> result = LinkedHashMap.newLinkedHashMap(map.size() + other.size());
```

Your loop would be simpler using `merge`, so logic like this:

```
public static Map<String, Object> mergeMaps(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> other) {
    Map<String, Object> result = LinkedHashMap.newLinkedHashMap(map.size() + other.size());
    result.putAll(map);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : other.entrySet()) {
        result.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (val1, val2) ->
                (val1 instanceof Map && val2 instanceof Map)
                ? mergeMaps((Map<String, Object>) val1, (Map<String, Object>) val2)
                : val2 );
    }
    return result;
}
```

The stream over config still causes a lot of copying from one map to another and those intermediate maps are lost at each stage. If you used your own `HashMap` as a marker you could avoid some of the new map construction and copying to next when you detect use of a map you've already created.

```
class MyHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {// or LinkedHM if prefer 
    MyHashMap(int size) {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

Then the first line of mergeMaps can bypass the `putAll` step as `map` parameter already contains what you need to return:

```
public static Map<String, Object> mergeMaps(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> other) {
    Map<String, Object> result = map;
    if (!(map instanceof MyHashMap)) {
        result = new MyHashMap(map.size() + other.size());
        result.putAll(map);
    }
    ...
}
```

But be careful with `MyHashMap` approach if you use the final output of the merge in another round of merges as then the input maps will be modified rather than reconstructed as copies.

If your original maps are `ConcurrentHashMap` then the `other.entrySet()` constructs new `Map.Entry` for each item, the loop might be better as:

```
for (String key : other.keySet()) {
    result.merge(key, other.get(key), ...
```

Comment: @Cristian I'll delete this answer if not helpful, I see that you've reposted the question on Code Review instead.